# Redirect abc.example.com to example.com/abc

Tags: redirect, subdomain, apache2

I have a domain `example.com` with the following DNS records:

```
Hostname           Type     Value
example.com        A        93.184.216.34
help.example.com   A        93.184.216.34
www.example.com    A        93.184.216.34
```

The file `/etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com.conf` is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com help.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/_site
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently both `help.example.com` and `www.example.com`  redirect to `example.com`.

My question is: How to redirect `help.example.com` to `example.com/help`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently both `help.example.com` and `www.example.com` redirect to
>   `example.com`.

No, they're both served by your server as that. Technically, there is no redirection involved.

> How to redirect help.example.com to example.com/help?

Enable `mod_rewrite` in your server with `a2enmod rewrite` (it's probably already enabled), then add this to your `VirtualHost`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^help\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/help$1 [R=301,L]
```

This would redirect all requests to `help.example.com` with a permanent redirect (301) to `http://example.com/help`.

Example:

```
http://help.example.com     -> http://example.com/help
http://help.example.com/foo -> http://example.com/help/foo
```

After editing your config, reload or restart your server.

Comment: +1 but it'd helpful if you could explain the `RewriteCond`. If I understand correctly, `RewriteRule` will only be applied to files matching the `RewriteCond`. But Is not clear to me what the various parts of `RewriteCond` are doing. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) is a condition for the `RewriteRule` which is only applied if both (`RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`) match. In this case the `RewriteRule` is pretty simple and matches every request.
The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable is the value of the HTTP request header sent by the client. We need it since we need to know the site the request was sent to and compare it to regex `^help\.example\.com$`. [\[NC\]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) matches case-insensitive, e.g. `help.Example.com`

Comment: [\[R\]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) is the redirect flag with an extra status code of 301 (default is 302) and 
[\[L\]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) is used to stop processing of any (possible) further rules.